How to correctly update values of input elements in if and else JavaScript statements
I have been trying to work around this code now without achieving the desired results


var milo = document.getElementById('milo');
var ovaltine = document.getElementById('ovaltine');
var bournvita = document.getElementById('bournvita');

var miloPrice = 2000.00;
var ovaltinePrice = 1500.00;
var bournvitaPrice = 1850.00;

var milocounter = 0;
var miloAmount = 0;

var ovaltinecounter = 0;
var ovaltineAmount;

var bournvitacounter = 0;
var bournvitaAmount = 0;

milo.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if (milocounter == 0) {
        milocounter += 1;
        miloAmount = miloPrice * milocounter;

        cartdetails.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="formilocounter" value="' + milocounter +'"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="formiloamount" value="' + miloAmount +'"></td>' +
            '</tr>' + '<br>';

    }

    else {
        milocounter += 1;
        miloAmount = miloPrice * milocounter;
        

        var formilocounter = document.getElementById('formilocounter');
        var formiloamount = document.getElementById('formiloamount');

        formilocounter.value = milocounter;
        formiloamount.value = miloAmount;
        
    }    
});

ovaltine.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if (ovaltinecounter == 0) {
        ovaltinecounter += 1;
        ovaltineAmount = ovaltinePrice * ovaltinecounter;


        cartdetails.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text"  id="forovaltinecounter" value="' + ovaltinecounter +'"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" id="forovaltineamount" value="' + ovaltineAmount +'"></td>' +
            '</tr>' + '<br>';
    }

    else {
        ovaltinecounter += 1;
        ovaltineAmount = ovaltinePrice * ovaltinecounter;

       

        var forovaltinecounter = document.getElementById('forovaltinecounter');
        var forovaltineamount = document.getElementById('forovaltineamount');

        forovaltinecounter.value = ovaltinecounter;
        forovaltineamount.value = ovaltineAmount;

    }
});

bournvita.addEventListener('click', function(){
 

    if (bournvitacounter == 0) {
        bournvitacounter += 1;
        bournvitaAmount = bournvitaPrice * bournvitacounter;

        cartdetails.innerHTML += '<tr>' +

            '<td ><input type="text" id="forbournvitacounter" value="' + bournvitacounter +'"></td>' +
            '<td ><input type="text" id="forbournvitaamount" value="' + bournvitaAmount +'"></td>' +
            '</tr>' + '<br>';

    }

    else {
        bournvitacounter += 1;
        bournvitaAmount = bournvitaPrice * bournvitacounter;

        var forbournvitacounter = document.getElementById('forbournvitacounter');
        var forbournvitaamount = document.getElementById('forbournvitaamount');

        forbournvitacounter.value = bournvitacounter;
        forbournvitaamount.value = bournvitaAmount;
    }

});
<article>
    <div id="milo" >
        <img src="images/milo.jfif"><br>
        <label>2,000.00</label>
    </div>
    
    <div id="ovaltine">
        <img src="images/ovaltine.jfif"><br>
        <label >1,500.00</label>
    </div>
    
    <div id="bournvita">
        <img src="images/bournvita.jfif"><br>
        <label>1,850.00</label>
    </div>
</article>

 <div id="cartdetails">

 </div>



When i click on any item first and again to add them to the cart, the code works fine. But the problem starts when i click on another item. The previous item(s) counter(s) reset to 1. But if i click on the previous items again, the correct counter resurfaces. Now, if i click on any new item, every previous item counter resets to 1 until i go back to click on them.
Please how do i make this work that all items counter retain their values in the  values whenever a new item is added to the cart. THANK YOU!!!

Please add a minimal reproducible example (ie JS + HTML)

I don't see anything wrong with the code you shared, it could be a side effect from somewhere else

@derpirscher As advised, i have reduced the example to minimal code, can you please take a look again? Thank You!

Looks like you ignored the word "reproducible" in [mre]. We can not execute what you have currently shown us, because you access objects out of nowhere. (As to be expected, the above code leads to nothing more than "Uncaught ReferenceError: milo is not defined" in the browser console.)

Okay, now you added a bit more (FYI: Relying on the browser automatically creating global objects matching HTML element IDs, is a really bad practices), but it still keeps throwing errors further down the line.)

Where exactly did you initialise the values of the counters?

@TheTeabagCoder it looks okay, but not the desired result. For instance, if milo is clicked first 3times, everything looks okay. But if i click bournvita afterwards, milocounter's value resets to 1 instead of staying at 3.

@C3roe i am just getting a hang of the platform. Please excuse my inappropriateness

@IlijaVuk the initializations have now been included in the code samples. Any solutions now please?

Either use cartdetails.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', your HTML goes here) or formilocounter.setAttribute("value", milocounter); etc - the issue is that the innerHTML of cartdetails has value="1" for those inputs ... so when you add to it, it resets to that value ... another option is to NOT use inputs there :p

The issue happens due to the fact that you are appending to the innerHTML, the first time you add a new product. The innerHTML for the already existing products in your cart, contains value="1" every time. You are increasing the value later on by setting element.value = ... - but those dynamic changes to the value property, are not reflected by the value attribute in the innerHTML.

@JaromandaX I tried your suggestions and everything is working as i initially wanted. I used input actually because cartdetails is in a form that i want to retrieve its data with $_POST[]. Thank you so much!!

@C3roe Thank you for the edits, time and suggestions.

The issue seems to be in the inputs that you're rendering. Even though you're updating the values of those inputs, their value is not being updated in the HTML of your code snippets.
If you inspect the cart div while you click on the product items, you'll notice that the "value" is always 1.
I guess this is happening because you're changing the cart by appending via innerHTML, and then the HTML representation gets rerendered with the value that's inside the HTML. To fix this specific problem you should use the appendChild method.
An alternative approach would be to use paragraphs instead of inputs if they're not explicitly required.
Here's a code sandbox in which I replaced all of those inputs with texts and you'll notice that it now works as intended: Code Sandbox
Here's the updated script.js file:
var milo = document.getElementById("milo");
var ovaltine = document.getElementById("ovaltine");
var bournvita = document.getElementById("bournvita");

var miloPrice = 2000.0;
var ovaltinePrice = 1500.0;
var bournvitaPrice = 1850.0;

var milocounter = 0;
var miloAmount = 0;

var ovaltinecounter = 0;
var ovaltineAmount;

var bournvitacounter = 0;
var bournvitaAmount = 0;

milo.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (milocounter == 0) {
    milocounter += 1;
    miloAmount = miloPrice * milocounter;

    cartdetails.innerHTML +=
      "<tr>" +
      '<td><p id="formilocounter">' +
      milocounter +
      "</p></td>" +
      '<td><p id="formiloamount" >' +
      miloAmount +
      "</p></td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "<br>";
  } else {
    milocounter += 1;
    miloAmount = miloPrice * milocounter;

    var formilocounter = document.getElementById("formilocounter");
    var formiloamount = document.getElementById("formiloamount");

    formilocounter.innerHTML = milocounter;
    formiloamount.innerHTML = miloAmount;
  }
});

ovaltine.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (ovaltinecounter == 0) {
    ovaltinecounter += 1;
    ovaltineAmount = ovaltinePrice * ovaltinecounter;

    cartdetails.innerHTML +=
      "<tr>" +
      '<td><p id="forovaltinecounter">' +
      ovaltinecounter +
      "</p></td>" +
      '<td><p id="forovaltineamount" >' +
      ovaltineAmount +
      "</p></td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "<br>";
  } else {
    ovaltinecounter += 1;
    ovaltineAmount = ovaltinePrice * ovaltinecounter;

    var forovaltinecounter = document.getElementById("forovaltinecounter");
    var forovaltineamount = document.getElementById("forovaltineamount");

    forovaltinecounter.innerHTML = ovaltinecounter;
    forovaltineamount.innerHTML = ovaltineAmount;
  }
});

bournvita.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (bournvitacounter == 0) {
    bournvitacounter += 1;
    bournvitaAmount = bournvitaPrice * bournvitacounter;

    cartdetails.innerHTML +=
      "<tr>" +
      '<td><p id="forbournvitacounter">' +
      bournvitacounter +
      "</p></td>" +
      '<td><p id="forbournvitaamount" >' +
      bournvitaAmount +
      "</p></td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "<br>";
  } else {
    bournvitacounter += 1;
    bournvitaAmount = bournvitaPrice * bournvitacounter;

    var forbournvitacounter = document.getElementById("forbournvitacounter");
    var forbournvitaamount = document.getElementById("forbournvitaamount");

    forbournvitacounter.innerHTML = bournvitacounter;
    forbournvitaamount.innerHTML = bournvitaAmount;
  }
});


thank you for the response. I used inputs because cartdetails is actually in a form which i intend to retrieve all its data on the destination page with $_POST[]. I have searched a while but couldn't find another method to retrieve a submitted form data without input values. I know its due to my beginner level though!
